# Tab Settings Not Available on Permission Set

Tags: standard-objects, tab, permission-sets, summer14

I just noticed that Tab Settings are no longer available in my permission sets in Salesforce. My Opportunities tab is defaulting to hidden for this permission set, so my users aren't able to access it. Tab Settings have been visible on permission sets in the past and [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPwpj.jpg) says that they should be there, as well. Perhaps this is a result of the Summer '14 release.

Has anyone else encountered this or found a solution? Thanks!

[image: No Tab Settings in Permission Sets]

Comment: what is your profile are you a system admin?

Comment: I have my production org at Summer 14 and Sandbox still in Spring 14 and I have the tab section available in both. What license type is your permission set setup for, maybe that feature isn't available for that license type?

Comment: Hm, Interesting. It's set up to be used with the Salesforce user license. I actually just noticed that Tab Settings is available for other objects in this permission set, but not on Opportunities. Did you happen to check Opportunities?

Comment: Yes, I checked the Opportunities object. I'm assuming you have all the necessary permissions? https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_tab_visibility.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Yes - I am a system admin. Also, I mentioned this below, but I just noticed that some objects have Tab Settings (Cases, Households both have it) and some don't (Opps, Accounts, and Contacts don't).

Comment: Yes - I am a system admin.

Comment: Are you editing an existing permission set or did you try creating a new one? If it works in a new one then my guess would be something got goofed up in the metadata of the existing one.

Comment: You're right, the Tab Settings show when I create a new permission set.

Comment: Salesforce R&D has been notified for this issue. I'll update if known issue is created so it can be tracked when it'll be fixed.

Answer (score 7):

I encountered same issue. And the solution which worked for me was that while creating the permission set I was not selecting any User License in the picklist. I created a new permission set with User License as 'Salesforce' and then option for Tab settings in opportunity object became enabled.

May be this could help.